# [algolia][Angular]Getting facets list in front

Tags: angularjs, algolia

I am working on a simple search AngularApp with Algolia. I can retrieve search from Algolia but i can't find how to get the list of possible facets and their possibles values. 
I want to be able to setup the filters dynamically so that if a facets change in the Algolia dashboard, I don't need to modify the app.

I found a command that seems to return the right data but it doesn't work :

```
index.getSettings(function(err, content) {
  console.log(content);
});
```

This is getting an error "This method is only available in HTTPS"
And when i use the REST API to get it myself through https i get a 403 forbidden.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `getSettings` method with the search-only API key, that's for security reason.

If you need to get all the available attributes for faceting, you can do an empty/blank search with `facets: '*'` (and eventually set the number of hits per page to `0` to not fetch any hit) to get all faceted attributes:

```
index.search('', {facets: '*', hitsPerPage: 0}, function(err, content) {
  console.log(Object.keys(content.facets));
});
```

Comment: It's working, thanks. a bit counter-intuitive but functional.